# I’m being asked to come back into work despite government guideline to stay at home- What are my rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, workplace, covid-19

I work in an administrative role at the NHS.
Since the lock down measures started in the UK, I have been working from home.

As demand on the NHS has been increasing substantially, management asked our team if individuals would be willing to come into the office to aid with the demand.

I initially agreed, however I did not at the time understand that this also meant I would be on-call to assist in clinical areas holding Covid patients. This is absolutely a no-go for me as I live with a family member who is in the extremely high risk category.

I had communicated to management this misunderstanding, and that I would not be willing to attend clinical areas but would be willing to assist onsite with my administrative duties if needed. I received verbal pressure to continue with what I originally, and erroneously agreed to. They gave me assurance that I wouldn't be assigned to clinical areas and said I will receive PPE training adjusted to the role i would be redeployed too.

Now with the the rapidly approaching peak death rate in the UK, with ambulance response times etc uncertain. I am very worried about my family member and am not willing to attend the office any longer.

I can do my regular duties from home, but management are telling me I cannot - without explaining what it is that I cannot do from home. They are pressuring me by saying they won't pay me for each day, for which I'm assigned, that I do not come into the office (I'm a non-permament employee).

Is it legal for them to demand that I attend the office without clarifying what I cannot do from home?
If so, can they force me to come on site by threatening my employment?

I feel like I am being pressured to put my loved ones' at undue risk.

Comment: Is the family member one of the people being instructed to 'shield' and not leave the house at all? Government guidance should be in your favour in this case, but I realise that guidance is not ideal here.

Comment: Yes my family member has been advised to shield.

Comment: As you work for the NHS are you a member of a union? Therefore have access to legal support? ACAS may be a good source of free competent advice but they have high call volumes in the present circumstances 0300 123 1100 https://www.acas.org.uk/contact. A high street solicitor might offer you a free half hour via voice or video if you cannot meet in person. I wish I had something useful - good luck to you.